# Android: Send push-notifications to specific user

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I try to use parse.com for the first time.

I know that I can create users with this:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(userName);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setEmail("email@example.com");
            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                    } else {
                        // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                        // to figure out what went wrong
                    }
                }
            });
```

Now I wonder, how I can later login as a user and how can I send a push-notification to a specific user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can login using the logInInBackground method

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground("myUsername", "myPassword", new 

LogInCallback() {
  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
    if (user != null) {
      // Hooray! The user is logged in.
    } else {
      // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
    }
  }
});
```

To send a push notification to the user you need to add the `ParseUser` pointer or a unique value like the username to the `ParseInstallation` then you can target the user using a unique channel or [advanced targeting](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications-using-advanced-targeting)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! If I still Need to Point the unique user value to the ParseInstallation, what is the Point in loggin in? I thought if I log in, parse would know which Installation is related to which session, so I could send a push to a user. Another question: The "advanced targeting" is something I have to code in "Cloud Code"? So I Need a Webhook for my Server, so I can start to push the notification from my Server?

Comment: A user could be logged in to multiple devices and many users could use one device. Installations track a device not a user. To target a user you need to associate it with a device because pushes can only target a device.
As far as I know, advanced targeting does not require cloud code. You essentially select installations like you do with any ParseQuery, then you can use that subset of installations as the target of the push.

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/advanced-push-targeting-on-android-and-ios/

Comment: Hi progNewbie, if this addresses your problem please accept the answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: I still don't understand from where the ParseQuery code is executed. I have a tcp-server communicating with my App. And I want to send specific push-notifications to specific users from my server. So I need to send a parsequery from my java-server to Parse.com, so that parse.com would send push-notifications to my app-client. For this I would need a Webhook right?

Comment: You can use the Rest API to send a push notification from your Java server.